# Perl recursive code for scanning directory tree

Tags: perl, recursion, directory

In this script that scan a directory recursively, i would like to know what happen when the "ScanDirectory($name)" is called -> does the "next" get executed right after?

Cause if the @names gets populated with new directories after each loop then we get inside the first directory in @names, and if there is other directories there Scandirectory is called again but the other directories in the previous @names are replaced and so they are not treated by the loop? Sorry if i don't make sense.

i know there is already a module for this purpose, but i want to improve my understanding of how this loop code works so i can deal with recursive code in other situations

```
sub ScanDirectory {

  my $workdir = shift;
  my $startdir = cwd;

  chdir $workdir or die;
  opendir my $DIR, '.' or die;
  my @names = readdir $DIR or die;
  closedir $DIR;

  foreach my $name (@names) {
    next if ($name eq ".");
    next if ($name eq "..");

    if (-d $name) {
      ScanDirectory($name);
      next;
    }

  }
  chdir $startdir or die;
}

ScanDirectory('.');
```

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html

Comment: thank you, i know there is already a module for this purpose, but i wanted to improve my understanding of how this loop code works so i can deal with recursive code in other situations.

Comment: I recommend checking out [Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/)--it's free and covers quite a few situations in which one would use recursion (including directory walking functions), as well as other ways that functional programming techniques can be used in Perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this your code?

In the subroutine you call `my @names = readdir` that defines a new lexically scoped variable, so each recursion will create a new instance of that variable. It might work if you use `our` instead of `my`. Variables defined with `our` are packaged scope which means each call will use the same `@names` variable. Actually not even then. You're cleaning out the previous value of the variable with your `readdir`.

You'll be better off using [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html). `File::Find` comes with most Perl installations, so it's always available.

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

use File::Find;

my @names;
find ( sub {
          next if $_ eq "." or $_ eq "..";
          push @names, $File::Find::name;
     }, "."
);
```

This is simpler to understand, easier to write, more flexible, and much more efficient since it doesn't call itself recursively. Most of the time, you'll see this without the `sub` being embedded in the function:

```
my @names;
find ( \&wanted, ".");

sub wanted {
    next if $_ eq "." or $_ eq "..";
    push @names, $File::Find::name;
}
```

I prefer to embed the subroutine if the subroutine is fairly small. It prevents the subroutine from wandering away from the `find` call, and it prevents the mysterious instance of `@names` being used in the subroutine without a clear definition.

Okay, they're both the same. Both are subroutine references (one is called `wanted` and one is an anonymous subroutine). However, the first use of `@names` doesn't appear so mysterious since it's literally defined on the line right above the `find` call.

If you must write your own routine from scratch (maybe a homework assignment?), then don't use recursion. use `push` to push the **reversed** `readdir` into an array.

Then, pop off the items of the array one at a time. If you find a directory, read it (again in reverse) and push it onto  your array. Be careful with `.` and `..`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advices. The code is actually from a book "system adminstration with perl". In the next page the author introduce the file::find module to make this task easier. i just wanted to understand this fully before moving on.

Answer (score 0):

This is strangely-written code, especially if it is published in a book.

Your confusion is because the `@names` array is declared *lexically*, which means it exists only for the extent of the current block, and is unique to a prticular stack frame (subroutine call). So each call of `scan_directory` (local identifiers shouldn't really contain capital letters) has its own independent `@names` array which vanishes when the subroutine exits, and there is no question of *"replacing"* the contents.

Also, the `next` you're referring to is redundant: it skips to the next iteration of the `@names` array, which is just what would happen without it.

It would be much better written like this

```
sub scan_directory {
  my ($workdir) = @_;

  my $startdir = cwd;
  chdir $workdir or die $!;

  opendir my $dh, '.' or die $!;

  while (my $name = readdir $dh) {
    next if $name eq '.' or $name eq '..';
    scan_directory($name) if -d $name;
  }

  chdir $startdir or die $!;
}

scan_directory('.');
```