# need to modify perl Deep::Hash::Utils

Tags: perl

i am very new to perl. i am trying to use the below code from CPAN.

```
my $C;

# Recursive version of C<each>;
sub reach {
    my $ref = shift;


    if (ref $ref eq 'HASH') {


        if (defined $C->{$ref}{v}) {
            if (ref $C->{$ref}{v} eq 'HASH') {
                if (my @rec = reach($C->{$ref}{v})) {
                    return ($C->{$ref}{k},@rec);
                } 
            } elsif (ref $C->{$ref}{v} eq 'ARRAY') {
                if (my @rec = reach($C->{$ref}{v})) {
                    if (defined $C->{$ref}{k}) {
                        return $C->{$ref}{k},@rec;
                    }
                    return @rec;
                } 

            }
            undef $C->{$ref};
        } 


        if (my ($k,$v) = each %$ref) {
            $C->{$ref}{v} = $v;
            $C->{$ref}{k} = $k;
            return ($k,reach($v));
        }

        return ();


    } elsif (ref $ref eq 'ARRAY') {


        if (defined $C->{$ref}{v}) {
            if (ref $C->{$ref}{v} eq 'HASH' || 
                ref $C->{$ref}{v} eq 'ARRAY') {

                if (my @rec = reach($C->{$ref}{v})) {
                    if (defined $C->{$ref}{k}) {
                        return $C->{$ref}{k},@rec;
                    }
                    return @rec;
                } 
            } 
        }



        if (my $v = $ref->[$C->{$ref}{i}++ || 0]) {
            $C->{$ref}{v} = $v;
            return (reach($v));
        }

        return ();
    }
    return $ref;
}
```

input:

```
bar => {cmd_opts => { gld_upf => ['abc' , 'def']} }
```

current output:

```
[bar, cmd_opts, gld_upf, abc]

[bar, cmd_opts, gld_upf, def]
```

desired output:

```
[bar, cmd_opts, gld_upf, ['abc', 'def']]
```

also, what are the concepts that are being used in this code?
are there any books/courses i can take for this?

Comment: Need to clarify what precisely you want -- in general, not only for the given input example. To leave array-references as they are? Um ... all of them? What if they contain hashrefs, like `[ { a => 1 }, 'b' ]`?  Can you edit the question to clearly state your objective for how to change this?

Comment: As for concepts, the basics you need is the "reference" --- see tutorial [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut) and the full reference [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref), and a cookbook on complex data structures, [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc) (this sub navigates and "unpacks" one such thing).  The notion of [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) isn't Perl specific.  In general head to docs, [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/), and look around.

Comment: Then there are books, many.  A standard introduction to the language is _Learning Perl_, while "references" (needed in this question) are in the next book, _Intermediate Perl_. There is also a free book, [Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/)

Answer (score 1):

> also, what are the concepts that are being used in this code? are there any books/courses i can take for this?

The code mentioned by you from the [`Deep::Hash::Utils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Deep::Hash::Utils) CPAN module is mainly handling nested data structures.

A couple of places to read about these:

- the official docs: [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc) ; [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut) ; [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref) ;
- [Modern Perl](http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/modern_perl_2016_letter.pdf) by chromatic has a section on Nested Data Structures around page 60
- [Intermediate Perl: Beyond The Basics of Learning Perl 2nd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449393098) has a section about Nested Data Structures around page 44.

In the most basic case, in these nested data structures, every node has one of the following types:

- scalar
- hashref
- arrayref

In turn, the values in the array pointed to by an arrayref can be of type scalar/hashref/arrayref.
The same goes for the values of the hash pointed to by an arrayref, it can be of type scalar/hashref/arrayref.

This induces a [tree-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) structure. The algorithm for traversing such a tree is [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)
where some additional logic is required to check the type of the node and depending on the type decide how to proceed further down the tree.

To make a parallel, all of this is not that much different from traversing a filesystem hierarchy (see [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25175976/827519), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338531/827519)).

A [bigger list called perlres](https://github.com/thibaultduponchelle/perlres) on Perl resources is available.

---

In this specific case, the function `reach` from [`Deep::Hash::Utils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Deep::Hash::Utils) acts as an iterator, and it returns all paths descending from the root down to each leaf.
Whenever a `@path` to a leaf is found, its elements are compared side-by-side with another list called `@output`, and there are three cases:

- there's no element on that position, so we store it
- the elements are equal, so we skip them
- the elements are different, so we merge them together in a list

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Deep::Hash::Utils qw/reach/;

my $input = { bar => {cmd_opts => { gld_upf => ['abc' , 'def']} } };

my @output = ();

while (my @path = reach($input)) {
    for(my $i=0;$i<=$#path;$i++){
        if(defined $output[$i]) {
            if(ref($output[$i]) eq "") {
                if($output[$i] eq $path[$i]) {
                    next;
                };
                my $e1 = $output[$i];
                my $e2 = $path[$i];
                $output[$i] = [$e1,$e2];
            }elsif(ref($output[$i]) eq "ARRAY"){
                push @{$output[$i]}, $path[$i];
            };
        } else {
            $output[$i] = $path[$i];
        };
    };
}

print Dumper \@output;
```

OUTPUT:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'bar',
          'cmd_opts',
          'gld_upf',
          [
            'abc',
            'def'
          ]
        ];
```